# form button issue in IE

Tags: html, css

In Chrome and Firefox the text in the button is wrapped and takes two lines.
However in Internet Explorer text in the button is not wrapped and the button is extended.

See button download for $4.99 on
http://www.manual-buddy.com/p/technics/rs1500usvolume1-service-manual.html

CSS :

```
.paypalOrderSubmitButton {
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 100%;
    font-weight: normal;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    padding: .5em 2em .55em;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    color: white!important;
    border: solid 1px #DA7C0C;
    background: #FAA51A;
    white-space: normal;
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Padding causes the button expands in IE, because IE will add the padding pixels.

You can use conditional tag to add the ie class depends on which IE browser. Then use the specific class to override your existing class to fix IE issues.

```
<!--[if IE ]><![endif]-->
<!doctype html>
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html lang="en" class="ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html lang="en" class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html lang="en" class="ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

Then in your css file, you need to write some code like:

```
.ie7 .paypalOrderSubmitButton, 
.ie8 .paypalOrderSubmitButton,
.ie9 .paypalOrderSubmitButton {
      width: 120px;
}
```

You can set the width, or you just set the padding to 0 for IE browsers.

This is a light-weighted way to fix IE issues.

Answer (score 0):

What version of IE are you using? IE always has problems unless you are using the latest version. Not sure if it will work, but try adding this to your CSS.

```
        clear:both;
```

If that doesn't work, JFIDDLE it and let me see.

Updating answer, older versions of IE don't accept new CSS, actually IE is touch to work around. Sometimes javascript has to be implemented, but that won't work even sometimes. Another thing you could try is

```
      word-wrap: normal;
      word-wrap: break-word;
      word-wrap: inherit;
```

If all else fails, JFIDDLE your website and i'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Set the width and height of the button and explicity add **white-space: normal** on element

```
style="width: 120px; height: 40px; white-space: normal"
```

You don't need char line breaks on the text. On IE it will be rendered wrong: "Downloadfor $4.99". Also, this trick doesn't work for some other browsers, as you can see [here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/button-with-line-breaks/).

Answer (score 0):

You can also try adding this to the list of CSS properties:

```
display: table\9;
```

That is a CSS hack to target IE only.

I'd suggest doing something like [Harry Roberts' suggestion to use a shame.css file that is IE hack specific](http://csswizardry.com/2013/04/shame-css/). That way it's easier to maintain your CSS as IE version support is slowly dropped.

Answer (score 0):

Does it is a problem if you use `width` ?

```
.paypalOrderSubmitButton {
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 100%;
    font-weight: normal;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    padding: .5em 2em .55em;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    color: white!important;
    border: solid 1px #DA7C0C;
    background: #FAA51A;
    white-space: normal;
    width: 120px;  // I have added one here additional
}
```

Of course: the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KdXwD/)

Answer (score 0):

Its because you have give padding in em (padding: .5em 2em .55em;)

Try giving it in px